# Update dynamically meter element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the value of a meter element with JavaScript. I use the code below. But this isn’t working. I think the part $('#meter1').html(data['meter1']); isn’t correct.  But I can’t figure out what this should be.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <meter id="meter1" value="0" min="0" low="5" high="10" max="15" ></meter>
  <script src='/js/meter.js'></script>
</html>
```

meter.js

```
$(window).load(function meter(){
  $(function meter() {
        $.get('/meter.php', function(data) {
            $('#meter1').html(data['meter1']);
        });
        setTimeout(meter, 10000);
  });
});
```

output meter.php: {"meter1": "5"}

Comment: What isn't working ?

Comment: Log `data` and `typeof data`.

Comment: result must be in data so add debugger and check what you received in success and it might be like this  `data.meter1`

Comment: Try setting header to JSON in your PHP file: `header('Content-Type: application/json');` It's probably being sent as text. Or in javascript `data = JSON.parse(data);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safest way:

```
$(function(){
  setInterval(function(){
    $.getJSON('/meter.php').done(function(data){
      $('#meter1').val(parseInt(data.meter1));
    }).fail(function() {
      alert("JSON Request error.");
    })
  },10000)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Do like this:

```
$.get('/meter.php', function(data) {
    $('#meter1').val(data.meter1);
});
```

Comment: `data['meter1']` and `data.meter1` are identical

Comment: isn't this `data['meter1']` wrong way to access json data?

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay at this point it's a regular JS object, however you may be right that OP wants to change `value` insted of textContent/html inside.

Comment: Yes, @Walk, that would be a clue to correct his code.

Comment: Thats what I have suggested